# How to build opencv correctly in windows to get "opencv_createsamples.exe"

Tags: windows, visual-studio, opencv, mingw

I want to learn and use haarcascade classifier using OpenCV for detection of object of my choice. I searched the internet and found that `createsamples` utility helps in creating dataset for positive and negative images. I know how to install OpenCV in python (`pip install opencv-python` works perfectly) but since I need to use that utility I need to build the OpenCV for my windows system.

---

### My attempts to install OpenCV in windows

**Attempt 1 : using MinGW and cmake**

- cloned latest OpenCV using git at `"C:\OpenCV"` from https://github.com/opencv/opencv
- Installed cmake
- created build using cmake at `"C:\OpenCV\build"` using MinGW(64 bit) build system with default options
- ran `mingw32-make`
- ran `mingw32-make install`

It created an  install directory in `"C:\OpenCV\build\install"`

but to my surprise `opencv_createsamples.exe` was not present there

`opencv_visualisation.exe`, `opencv_annotation.exe`, `opencv_version.exe` etc. are present

[screenshot of install files generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCtdt.jpg)

[screenshot of build options selected in cmake by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTs1i.jpg)

It is clear `BUILD_opencv_apps` is `true` by default and other apps were created except this one

still in source folder : `createsamples.cpp` is present in `"C:\OpenCV\apps\"` along with `opencv_visualisation.cpp` and others

**Attempt 2: visual studio 14_15 build from official site**

- Downloaded OpenCV latest 4.0.1 from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases/download/4.0.1/opencv-4.0.1-vc14_vc15.exe from https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases webpage
- extracted the opencv build at `"C:\OpenCV401\"`

still to my surprise at `"C:\OpenCV401\build\x64\vc14\bin"` no `opencv_createsamples.exe`
likewise other files are present

[screenshot of files present in build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CoYr.png)

**Attempt 3**

- This time I downloaded visual studio 10 build from this github page : https://github.com/abreheret/opencv3.2.0_build
- here at `<OpenCV_DIR>/x64/vc10/bin/` all the amazing files are present

[screenshot of files present in this build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmLfj.jpg)

---

So, my question is :

- Why that utility was not built from the source using MinGW and cmake in my first attempt
- Why they have not included in the official build
- How to build using MinGW and cmake to get that utility correctly (maybe some build configuration needed?)

Comment: 1) OpenCV is a library, it has some samples and utility apps, but they are not built by default, not everyone needs them. 2) Their official build is the library, not utilities or apps. The correct way is via the cmake, but make sure that you tick the option Build_opencv_apps and then in the log where it says OpenCV modules: it has a line that says `Applications: apps`. For the third question I let someone else answer... however I think the title should be more towards the last question so that more people answer you

Comment: So it means it is the problem from my part when using cmake with mingw which is the reason why I could not get that utility?

Comment: @api55 I am using default options in `cmake` and `BUILD_opencv_apps` is `true` in configuration and also other apps were generated like `opencv_visualisation.exe` which are part of apps as mentioned in my post but not `opencv_createsamples.exe`

Comment: I have deleted the last question and changed the title to an appropriate one. I have now also included screenshot for the options involved in cmake configuration while building in the question

Comment: When you open the visual studio solution, does it have a folder (in the solution explorer) that says application? does this folder have a project named opencv_createsamples?

Comment: @api55 In the source folder of OpenCV there is `C:\\OpenCV\apps` there exists different folders like `traincascade`, `annotation` etc. including `createsamples`
[screenshot for folder](https://imgur.com/oz6q2ng)
<hr>
[screenshot for createsamples folder](https://imgur.com/qZ7N9UG)

Comment: I do not have visual studio installed in my system
`1st` one is using MinGW and cmake
`2nd` one is already built release (using visual studio 14-15) found in opencv github page
`3rd` one is some guy's build (using visual studio 10) on github which is complete

Comment: I want to build like the that guy's github page 
 https://github.com/abreheret/opencv3.2.0_build

Comment: I actually get the same result as in that github... But I use visualstudio, not sure what is different... I may try later in another computer with ming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Createsamples was disabled in latest OpenCV (4.0 and greater): [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/apps/CMakeLists.txt#L53).

Comment: Just addng a little bit more to your answer, The reason is in this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/13231)... Long story short, it used C Api and they didn't rewrite it in C++

Comment: Thanks for clarification that they have removed that utility

Comment: Now I should find other ways to build the dataset for my classifier

Comment: I would suggest just building stable version 3.4 from the repo and using it there.