# Instead of opencv_createsamples (OpenCV 4.0 and later) on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, opencv, haar-classifier

I want to train my own Haar cascade to recognise my phone in images.

I have a large number of negative/background images and an image of my phone. I wanted to use opencv_createsamples() to generate a large number of positive images, using the negative/background images and the image of my phone.

However according to [How to build opencv correctly in windows to get "opencv_createsamples.exe"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310798/how-to-build-opencv-correctly-in-windows-to-get-opencv-createsamples-exe), opencv_createsamples() has been disabled.

Is there another module I could use, or should I install an older version of OpenCV? I'm on Python (3.7.4) and Windows (10).

I've checked out https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html but they say the tutorials may be obsolete. Could someone recommend an up to date source of information?

I really want to learn how do this in Windows, not using a Linux server.

Comment: you can/should just use an older opencv version (3.x). Cascade classifier training has a lot of old C API code, which is removed in opencv 4. Afaik you can still use the detector in opencv 4, only the training apps were removed.

Comment: @Micka, do you know if the 'Installation by Using the Pre-built Libraries' option on https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html lets you build Haar cascades (including the use of OpenCV_createsamples()), or if you really do need to go for the make-your-own-OpenCV-with-libraries-from-source-files option? It says the pre-built option 'doesn’t take advantage of the most advanced technologies we integrate into our library', does it refer to utilising GPU? Thanks

Comment: afaik, cascade classifier training doesnt use gpu in away setup (not even self-compiled), so I think you can use the prebuilt binaries without disadvantages. Not sure about AVX2 optimizations and/or IPP, TBB, etc., which maybe could give a speedup (but not guaranteed, I dont know how well the old C API code was optimized).